# Правила вложения тегов HTML

Tags: html, img, span

Где то читал, что нельзя размещать блочные элементы внутри встроенных. Все, конечно, будет работать, если даже запихать дивы в ссылки. Но хаоса в жизни мне и так хватает, по этому хочется делать как положено..

Поэтому вопрос. Валидна ли такая вложенность?

```html
<a href="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

И еще! Валидно ли использовать тег a как блочный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, валидно. И `a` можно сделать блочным.
Update тег имг не закрыт, надо сделать так: `<img ...  />`

Значение display: block в стиле или цсс сделает элемент блочным.

Answer (score 0):

Да, валидно. Нельзя блочные внутри инлайновых.

`<span> - inline;
<div> - block;
<p> - block;`

А вообще почитайте статью о [Строчных и блочных элементах](https://html5book.ru/block-inline-elements/)